# How safe is it to assume the registry hives will always be the same?

Tags: c#, .net, windows, registry

I am writing a console application that allows you to interact with the registry. The application starts off with the string `path` been set empty. When the user types `ls`, I want it to list all the registry hives (because they are currently at the top level of the local machine). However after some extensive research I cannot find a way to get all registry hives on the current machine. How safe is it to assume that these hives will *always* be there?

```
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT
HKEY_CURRENT_USER
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE
HKEY_USERS
HKEY_CURRENT_CONFIG
```

If it is not safe to think these are always there, how could I get them dynamically?

(and sorry if "hives" is not the correct term for root level subkeys, I'm quite new to dealing with the registry)

Comment: Since they are hard coded in `Microsoft.Win32.RegistryHive` enum, I can assume they will be always there...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "Standard Hives" are documented, so they will not change.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724877(v=vs.85).aspx

> To open a key, an application must supply a handle to another key in
> the registry that is already open. The system defines predefined keys
> that are always open. Predefined keys help an application navigate in
> the registry and make it possible to develop tools that allow a system
> administrator to manipulate categories of data. Applications that add
> data to the registry should always work within the framework of
> predefined keys, so administrative tools can find and use the new
> data.
>
> An application can use handles to these keys as entry points to the registry. These handles are valid for all implementations of the registry, although the use of the handles may vary from platform to platform.

`HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT` is not a hive, it is a view into other hives, but is a predefined key that will always be open.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724836(v=vs.85).aspx

See @Eser 's comment above that they are also in the `Microsoft.Win32.RegistryHive` enumeration.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ctb3kd86(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Thanks, but is there a way I could possibly detect the hives in code, because my hives are slightly different, which makes me think other people's might be too? (I have `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT`, which isn't documented as standard.)

Comment: I updated my answer. `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT` is not a hive, it is a view of a combination of other hives. With that said, it is listed in the second link as a predefined key that is always open.

Comment: So everything in `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT` are shortcuts to other locations in other hives?

Comment: Correct. _The HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT key provides a view of the registry that merges the information from these two sources. HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT also provides this merged view for applications designed for previous versions of Windows._ https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724475(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: How would I access `Microsoft.Win32.RegistryHive`?

Comment: It is in `mscorlib.dll`, so it should be available by default after including `using Microsoft.Win32;`

Comment: Sorry for the long wait for accepting the answer, I completely forgot about this!